# Efficiently using pass and continue in a for loop of elements Python

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, compare

The code below runs the function `main()` where the `skipper` function checks if the values of `a` and `b` are within the max and min range that is set within the `skipping elements` dictionary. The values are the returned with a bool value and depending on the return it will either pass to the next index of `a` and `b` or continue onto the next section (section 2) where the index values of `a` and `b` are added and compared to range of the max and min values of total in the `skipping_elements` dictionary once again. Right below is the code I use for skipping, is there a better way to implement it to the `main()` function since I do not want to copy and paste that every time I do a compare. The code is functional as is.

Code used for skipping

```
        if skip_return:
            #Passing
            pass
        else:
            #Skipping 
            continue
```

Main() Components:

```
a = [12,5,1,2,3,4]
b = [14,7,2,8,11,4]

skipping_elements = {
    'a max': 15,
    'a min': 3,
    'b max': 15,
    'b min': 5,
    'total max': 20,
    'total min': 12
}

def skipper(*values):

    selector= values[0][1][0]
    if selector == 1:
        a_val = values[0][0][0]
        b_val = values[0][0][1]
        
        a_comp = True if a_val <= skipping_elements['a max'] & a_val >= skipping_elements['a min'] else False
        b_comp = True if b_val <= skipping_elements['b max'] & b_val >= skipping_elements['b min'] else False
        
        expected_output = a_comp & b_comp
    
    elif selector == 2:
        total_val= values[0][0][0]
        
        min_val = skipping_elements['total min']
        max_val = skipping_elements['total max']
    
        expected_output = (total_val <= max_val) & (total_val >= min_val)
        
    return expected_output
```

Running Main:

```
def main():
    for x in range(len(a)):
        
        def condition_check(*check_element):
            elements = skipper(check_element)
            if elements:
                return True
            else: 
                print('Skipped at first check')
                return False
        
        skip_return = condition_check([a[x],b[x]], [1])
        
        if skip_return:
            #Passing
            pass
        else:
            #Skipping
            print('Skipped at second check')
            continue
            
        skip_return = condition_check([a[x] + b[x]], [2])

        if skip_return:
            #Passing
            pass
        else:
            #Skipping 
            continue
        
        print('no skips','a=',a[x],"b=", b[x],'total',a[x]+b[x])
    
main()
```

Output:

```
Skipped at first check
no skips a= 5 b= 7 total 12
Skipped at first check
Skipped at second check
Skipped at first check
Skipped at second check
no skips a= 3 b= 11 total 14
Skipped at first check
Skipped at second check
```

Comment: `if condition_check(..., 1) and condition_check(..., 2): print("no skips")`?

Comment: It more has to do with checking after every single condition_check. Instead of checking at once